# Tombstoning the last visited page the user was on

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to tombstone the last page that the user was on and to retrieve it when the user comes back to the app. All of the tombstoning examples on the Internet deal with saving some data or the state of the page that the user has edited somehow (i.e inputed text in the textbox). In my app I don't have anything for the user to modify/edit so I just want to save the last visited page that the user was on. I tried to use some online examples that used PhoneApplicationService.Current.State but with no success.

Thank you to anyone who would like to help me out resolving this issue!

Comment: When a user comes back from a tombstone, they're already taken to the last page they were on. If you have no custom data to save, it should be working for you without you having to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes it does work with back button but I just thought it would great if the user would be able to come back to the page by pressing the application icon also. Now it just starts the splash screen and navigates to the first page. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Technically speaking, that means the user has restarted your app (instead of it coming back from a tombstone). In this case, you'll need to write to IsolatedStorage because `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` only works whilst the apps is running or is tombstoned. If you restart the app, the `State` is cleared, which is why you weren't able to access it. I'll write some code in a second.

Comment: I've added code (it's untested, so let me know if an error is thrown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To locally store `persistent data` (data that should remain even when the user closes the app), you can use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

So, in your app's `Deactivated` event, you can write the page's name to Isolated Storage like this:

```
//You get the Isolated Storage for your app (other apps can't access it)
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

//if the file already exists, delete it (since we're going to write a new one)
if (isf.FileExists("lastpage.txt")) isf.DeleteFile("lastpage.txt");
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("lastpage.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf))
{
      //open a StreamWriter to write the file
      using (var sw = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
      {
           //NavigationService.CurrentSource returns the current page
           //we can write this to the file
           sw.WriteLine((Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).CurrentSource.ToString());
       }
}
```

This will write the current page's name to the Isolated Storage. Then, in your `OnNavigatedto` method of your main page (the page that first opens normally) you can read the file name and navigate to it:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

     string lastpage = string.Empty;

     if (isf.FileExists("lastpage.txt"))
     {
         using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("lastpage.txt", FileMode.Open, isf))
         {
             //read the file using a StreamReader
             using (var sr = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
             {
                 //get the uri we wrote and then convert it from a String to a Uri
                 lastpage = sr.ReadLine().Replace("file:///", "");

             }
          }


          (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(lastpage, UriKind.Relative));
       }
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

This should read in the file you saved and then convert the string into an actual URI that you can pass to the `NavigationService`.

You can then delete the text file after it's been read so that it doesn't always keep jumping to that page.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I thought that PhoneApplicationService.Current.State would also work if the user has pressed the Start button and returned to the app by pressing the app icon. But it does make sense to us IsolatedStorage. I will try this code and tell you how it went. Thanks once again!

Comment: Edited the text. You'll most likely only need the `deactivated` and `launching` events.

Comment: It did throw a couple of errors: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)  AND  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CurrentSource.get

Comment: Try replacing `NavigationService` with `(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame)`. So, for example, the last line in the code above will be `(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(pageToNavigate);`

Comment: Thank you! It eliminated the first error but this line sw.WriteLine(NavigationService.CurrentSource.ToString()); still gives the second error.

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes, I'll see if I can quickly create a new project.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for helping me out! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Move the `reading` code into your MainPage. The reason an error was thrown was because there wasn't a `NavigationService` object created at the time it was being called. You can override the `onNavigatedTo` method of your main page. I've also made a few changes, so make sure you have the new version.

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted!

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can use this for getting the page name ,`string PageName = (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationPage).Name;` for getting the current page name

Answer (score 1):

While I agree all the above options are possible, they are not really the correct way of doing something within a WP7.

It's better to construct a navigation page at the start of your app for properly controlling navigation, it also helps with managing back key events while using the app and prevents hiccups.

See Here for one example of implementing this:
[Properly Exiting Silverlight-based WP7](http://bit.ly/wvKx5U)

With this done use the advice on storing values in isolated storage / application settings to then just store the "Current Page" state value (e.g. value of Page.GamePage) then the app navigation will direct you accordingly.
BUT beware when just storing the current page itself as you also need to save the correct state of any values or User entered data on that page when it tombstones as well, this the above advice should lead you in the right direction.

Hope this helps